# Trademark symbol is displayed as raw text

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, symbols

if you visit `www.startwire.com` you'll see in the center of the page (in the yellow box, under the video) the following:

```
StartWire&trade;
```

in our dev and stage environments, this is not an issue, but it is in production. What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: What you have is `&amp;trade;`, I dunno ruby on rails though, but it's a server side problem as in the server is encoding everything on that page before sending. It even changes `http://startwire.com/linkedin/new?nopopup=true` to `http:&#47;&#47;startwire.com&#47;linkedin&#47;new?nopopup=true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the page source, you will see `&amp;trade;` - you are double encoding the entity.

This should be simply `&trade;`.

Comment: What are some possible causes of double encoding?

Comment: @Ramy - using any HTML encoding utility on strings being output would do this.

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML you have:

```
<h2>Sign-up now. StartWire&amp;trade; is completely FREE.</h2>
```

whereas the correct would be:

```
<h2>Sign-up now. StartWire&trade; is completely FREE.</h2>
```

Notice the extraneous `&amp;`. Look like you are double encoding something on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Is the content being "HTML encoded" (or whatever they call it) automatically, somewhere in the script? Because this is what appears in the HTML: `&amp;trade;`.
My suggestions would be to just use the symbol in your code (™). If that doesn't work, try escaping the `&` of `&trade;` using `\` (so that it becomes `\&trade;`).

Comment: +1 for suggesting the actual symbol, but you used the wrong one in your example. It should be StartWire™. Maybe I'm being lazy, but I rarely use html entities any more.

Answer (score 1):

If you check your page source it says:

```
&amp;trade;
```

This means that probably it took `&trade;` and transformed that into HTML. So the `&` becomes `&amp;`. This is probably due to the use of a [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function.

Make sure you do not do this conversion twice...

A possible cause of this is that you are taking the contents from a database and that you have encoded the entries **before** inserting them into the database and you encode them a second time when you retrieve them from this database.

Comment: not pulling anything from the DB here: `<h2 class="dark mbm mts">Sign-up now. StartWire&trade; is completely FREE.</h2>`

Comment: Is that your HTML code? What's happening with this afterwards? &#8482; should give the ™ as well.

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but i have checked your site it shows like you have write like

```
&amp;&trade;
```

simple write `&trade;`